# Passing multiple variables in <a href> using PHP and $_GET['']

Tags: php, get

I'm using PHP to create a link depending on a variable. Currently I have this line of code which I have used multiple times and works perfectly.

```
echo "<a href='specificAssignmentPage.php?
assignName=$value2'>$value2</a>";
```

The above is all on one line.
On the receiving page I have

```
$assignmentName = $_GET['assignName'];
```

which retrieves the value from the URL.

However I want to pass multiple variables through the link which I've attempted with

```
echo "<a href='specificAssignmentPage.php?assignName=$value2'teacherYes=$isTeacher>$value2</a>";
```

And received with

```
$assignmentName = $_GET['assignName'];
$isTeacher = $_GET['teacherYes'];
```

I get this error: "
Notice: Undefined index: teacherYes in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Quests/specificAssignmentPage.php on line 13"

I know that it's probably a basic syntax error with separating my statement but I would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: simple; you need the `&` separator

Comment: You should have a & in the place where you currently show a ' mark (after $value2).

Answer (score 2):

Use the `&` between each url parameters

```
?assignName=$value2&teacherYes=$isTeacher
```